# MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE, unreadable text

Tags: android

i use

```
    String[] projection = {MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM,
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION, 
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.YEAR,
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID};
Cursor cursor;
cursor = сontext.getContentResolver().query(
             MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,    
             projection, selection, null, null);
```

and get data from tracks

```
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Track =" + cursor.getString(3));
    Track track = new Track();
    track.setLocalId(cursor.getInt(0));
    track.setArtist(cursor.getString(1));
    track.setAlbum(cursor.getString(2));
    track.setTitle(cursor.getString(3));
    track.setPath(cursor.getString(4));
    track.setFileName(cursor.getString(5));
    track.setLength(cursor.getLong(6));
    track.setYear(cursor.getInt(7));
    track.setAlbumId(cursor.getLong(8));
    track.setGenre(context.getString(R.string.unknown_genre));
    tracks.add(track);
}
cursor.close();
```

In the first case, on my real device HTC One V, in Log i see:
Track =Eye of the tiger(OST Рокки Бальбоа),
the second, on Genymotion emulator for example, in Log:
Track =Eye of the tiger(OST ?????????? ??????????????)

Please tell me how to solve this problem?

Comment: And what are the original titles?

Comment: @m02ph3u5 Eye of the tiger(OST Рокки Бальбоа)  https://www.dropbox.com/s/4id75xjiuqpru7m/track.png?dl=0

Comment: So there's an issue with cyrillic characters - most probably with utf-8. What rom do you have on your HTC and which one in your emulator?

Comment: hello. did you solve the problem?. I have exactly the same problem with Cyrillic metadata of audio files

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43850060/cursor-getstringcursor-getcolumnindex-cant-return-normal-text-if-its-not